# LibGit2Sharp - Fetch, Push, Pull - Too many redirects or authentication replays

Tags: libgit2sharp

Too many redirects or authentication replays for DefaultCredential. While I used UsernamePasswordCredentials then It is working fine. I don't want pass username and password.

Comment: Please show us your current code, link to the library you are using, and provide a log of the error messages.

Comment: Code:CredentialsHandler _credentials = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials(); string cloneURl ="https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/xyz";
  Uri scd = new Uri(@"C:\\\Repository\\cloneDesignDepot" + Guid.NewGuid());
  var cloneOptions = new CloneOptions
  {BranchName = "master",Checkout = true,CredentialsProvider =_credentials };string clonerepositoryPath = string.Empty;clonerepositoryPath = Repository.Clone(cloneURl, scd.LocalPath, cloneOptions);

Comment: Error: Too many redirects or authentication replays Stack Trace    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
   at GitLibrary.Program.Clone() in C:\Repository\Practice\GitLibrary\GitLibrary\Program.cs:line 50

Answer (score 3):

The credentials are not accepted by the server. The server is either not set up to accept the NTLM/Kerberos credentials for the logged-in user, or the current user does not have permission to read from that repository.

Unless you are 100% sure that the credentials are right and there is no way they'll ever be wrong, you should not have your credentials callback always return the same information without checking whether those credentials have failed before. If you only ever return the same credentials and don't provide a way to stop, the library will keep looping.

In this case, the libgit2 WinHTTP code does not currently differentiate between URL redirects and authentication failures when it retries requests, so it stopped and gave you an error message as protection in case the server has a redirect loop; but in general you should not rely on this happening.